# Resource file (.resx) vs reflection to access an embedded resource

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reflection, embedded-resource

I may be missing something very simple here, but what's the benefit of using reflection to retrieve an embedded resource from the **same assembly that contains the resource** as opposed to simply retrieving it via an .resx file? I see this a lot but don't get it - is there a reason to use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource)` compared to resx file `Resources.resource`? Even Microsoft does it: [How to embed and access resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).

What I mean exactly: suppose I have an assembly `MyAssembly` that contains an embedded resource `Config.xml`. The assembly has `MyClass` that implements a method that returns said resource as a string:

```
public string GetConfigXML() // returns the content of Config.xml as a string
```

Often, I see this implemented like this, using reflection to retrieve the resource:

```
public string GetConfigXML()
{
    Stream xmlStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyAssembly.Config.xml"); 
    string xml = GetStringFromStream(xmlStream);
    return xml;
}
```

Why use `GetManifestResourceStream()` when you can:

1. add a resource file (`Resource.resx`) to the `MyAssembly` project in Visual Studio;
2. add `Config.xml` to the resource's 'Files';
3. get the content of `Config.xml` in a much simpler way: `string xml = Resource.Config;`

I don't know how Visual Studio handles .resx files internally, but I doubt it simply copies the resource into the .resx file (in which case you'd end up with duplicated resources). I assume it doesn't use reflection internally either, so why not simply use .resx files in situations like this, which seems much more performance-friendly to me?

Comment: Getting it via the assembly *might* do the culture aware satellite assembly loading for you, whereas loading the resx would leave you with the responsibility of choosing the correct one for the current culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but what's the benefit of using reflection to retrieve an embedded resource

The common benefit that's behind any reason to convert data from one format to another.  Speed, speed, speed and convenience.

XML is a pretty decent format to keep your resources stored in.  You'll have a very good guarantee that you can still retrieve the original resource 10 years from now when the original got lost in the fog of time and a couple of machine changes without good backups.  But it is quite a sucky format to have to read from, XML is very verbose and locating a fragment requires reading from the start of the file.

Problems that disappear when Resgen.exe compiles the .xml file into a .resource file.  A binary format that's fit to be linked into your assembly metadata and contains the original bytes in the resource.  And is directly mapped into memory when your assembly is loaded, no need to find another file and open it, read it and convert the data.  Big difference.

Do use the Resource Designer to avoid having to use GetManifestResourceStream() directly.  Yet more convenience.

Comment: Fair points, thank you. It seems to me, though, that the speed benefit of using reflection for a direct resource access would likely only become obvious if you were storing a large amount of resource files in .resx, while for a small number of embedded resources reflection would actually be slower (since you need to `GetManifestResourceStream` and then convert it to the appropriate format) compared to reading from .resx?

Comment: You seem to operating from the common myth that "Reflection is slow".  It is only slow when you compare, say, using a property directly vs using Reflection to obtain a property value.  Sure, you can't beat a nanosecond with Reflection.  GetManifestResourceStream is *not* slow compared to opening a file.  It is easily 50,000x faster, give or take an order of magnitude :)